# NodeJS: How to convert 'aggregation'(cursor) object to CSV and return a CSV response from a request using Express?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, csv, aggregation-framework, content-type

I want to convert the result from aggregate to a csv. In the code (or pseudocode) below the results of the aggregate are stored in variable ***cursor***

I want to return a csv as a response ( `res.send(csv)` ). Do I have to use `res.set('Content-Type', 'content-type: text/csv')` ?

The code below is a mix of NodeJs and pseudocode. Function `covert_to_csv` indicates my ignorance about the subject.

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    let agg=[ /*   a query in MongoDB   */]

    MongoClient.connect(URL,(err, client) => {

        res.set('Content-Type', 'content-type: text/csv');

        let collection = client.db('db').collection('col')
        let cursor = collection.aggregate(agg)

        let csv_file = covert_to_csv(cursor)

        csv_file.toArray((error, result) => {
            res.send(result);
    });

});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on port ${port}!`));
```

**Edit:**

In my original code i am getting a response in json.I run the following code:

```js
let agg=[ /*   a query in MongoDB   */]

let cursor = collection.aggregate(agg)

cursor.toArray((error, result) => {
          if(error) {
              return res.status(500).send(error);
          res.send(result);
```

I am getting this response from Postman in JSON :

```
[
    {
        "Source": "entso-e",
        "Dataset": "ActualTotalLoad",
        "AreaName": "Germany",
        "AreaTypeCode": "CTY",
        "MapCode": "DE",
        "ResolutionCode": "PT15M",
        "Year": "2018",
        "Month": "1",
        "Day": "2",
        "DateTimeUTC": "2018-01-02 00:00:00.0000000",
        "ActualTotalLoadValue": "41412.38",
        "UpdateTimeUTC": "2018-01-02 13:16:19.0000000"
    },
    {
        "Source": "entso-e",
        "Dataset": "ActualTotalLoad",
        "AreaName": "Germany",
        "AreaTypeCode": "CTY",
        "MapCode": "DE",
        "ResolutionCode": "PT15M",
        "Year": "2018",
        "Month": "1",
        "Day": "2",
        "DateTimeUTC": "2018-01-02 00:45:00.0000000",
        "ActualTotalLoadValue": "40785.17",
        "UpdateTimeUTC": "2018-01-02 13:16:19.0000000"
    },
    ..... (more documents)
    ]
```

Comment: Can you post a example response from the aggregation?, also, the MongoClient connect should be outside of the `app.get('/'...` because that will create a connection to mongo everytime someone makes a request

Comment: You are right about the "connect",i will fix it. I will post example in original question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a module like `json2csv` to do the job for you. Your example will look something like that

```
const { Parser } = require('json2csv');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    let agg = [/* mongo aggregation */]
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
    res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=\"' + 'download-' + Date.now() + '.csv\"');
    let cursor = collection.aggregate(agg)
    const fields = ['Source', 'Dataset', 'Areaname'];//all your field names
    const json2csvParser = new Parser({ fields });
    cursor.toArray((error, result) => {

       res.send(json2csvParser.parse(result))

    })
})
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.I tried to give u the bounty right away,but unfortunately i will have the permission to do this in 15 hours

Answer (score 1):

Try referring to https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-csv and set keys as header option to true